# Doctrine - load a YAML fixture with French characters

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, encoding, doctrine, yaml

My Doctrine 1.2 is integrated inside CodeIgniter as a hook and I know that my char-set is utf8 with collation utf8_unicode_ci.

I have two YAML files, one for creating the DB and its tables and one to load some test data. My data can contain French accents (çéïë...). In my schama.yml I have correctly specified the collation and char-set:

```
options:
  type: INNODB
  charset: utf8
  collate: utf8_unicode_ci
```

I double checked the settings in phpMyAdmin, everything is correct.

When I run my doctrine script from commandline to load my fixture to my one of my tables, all the French accents are replaced by junk!

Am I missing a setting or configuration or is there a bug in Doctrine?

Answer (score 3):

You should have in your /config/database.php Doctrine connection:

```
// Load the Doctrine connection
$doctrine = Doctrine_Manager::connection($db['default']['dsn'], $db['default']['database']);
```

To fix the problem with the encoding you have to add this line:

```
$doctrine->exec('set names utf8');
```

Comment: I had the same problem with CodeIgniter + Doctrine 1.2 and this solution fixes the problems with latin characters.